# How to create dialog without blocking main form?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

For now I can do:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionPATH_triggered() {
    std::unique_ptr<QDialog> win(new QDialog());
    win->exec();
}
```

Should I use `async` / run in separate threadto avoid blocking main window or is there way to subscribe to close even and delete / free object there?

Comment: @ratchetfreak it has no sense if OP use exec() http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-prop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use just `show()`

```
void MainWindow::on_actionPATH_triggered() {
    QDialog* win = new QDialog();
    //needed connect
    win->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);//we don't want memory leak
    win->show();
}
```

and use

```
win->setModal(false);//but it is default option, you don't need to change it
```

From [doc](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdialog.html#modal-prop):

> By default, this property is false and show() pops up the dialog as
>   modeless. Setting his property to true is equivalent to setting
>   QWidget::windowModality to Qt::ApplicationModal. exec() ignores the
>   value of this property and always pops up the dialog as modal.

`Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` will delete your dialog, when user close it.

You can also set parent to dialog:

```
QDialog* win = new QDialog(this);
```

In this case `win` will be delete with your mainWindow.

[Info about Qt parent child relationship](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html)

And you don't need here separate thread.